# Books on Fourier analysis and transform methods

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, book-recommendation

What are some books with examples for fourier analysis? The examples are the most important part here. I don't care about a book that has theory. I need something that has some worked examples and practical practice problems. I've looked through the other questions on here and non of them seem answer my question sufficiently. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Cost isn't a huge factor, passing my class is.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Consider Schaum's Outline

Comment: Alright I'll check that out thanks.